# Is there a way to append two dictionaries in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I would like to add two dictionaries and not update first one with second. The value will be a single variable or a list.
What I would like to achieve:

**Input:**

```
x = {"a": [1] }
y = {"a": [2, 3], "b": [2] }
```

**Output:**

```
z = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [2] }
```

It would be great if it could also accept a single int instead of only list as mentioned earlier:

**Input:**

```
x = {"a": 1 }
y = {"a": [2, 3], "b": [2] }
```

**Output:**

```
z = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [2] }
```

So looking for

```
z = append_dicts(x, y)
```

This is what I came up with.

```
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    """Given two dicts, append them into a new dict."""
    for key in x:
        if isinstance(x[key], list):
            y[key].extend(x[key])
        else:
            y[key].append(x[key])
    return y
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but this isn't a code-writing service. Have you tried something? What happened?

Comment: @vincent I read through the listed post but that approach updates the first dictionary with the second one losing values from the first.

Comment: @synergy You might need to implement it by youself. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: A defaultdict might be useful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: @jonrsharpe I posted my attempt. New to the service so wan't sure if I had to post my attempt.

Comment: @sangheestyle I did something very similar. Just wondering if there is a better way. Thanks :)

Comment: @synergy Good. But, one thing you might be interesting is check y after `merge_two_dicts` which you implemented. It's modified. If you don't care, it's fine otherwise, you might need to use `dict()` to copy `y` before you do something.

Comment: You may want to get your data in a consistent format.  It makes code much simpler.  Having to detect if something is a `int` or `list` every time makes for ugly code. `list`s of size 1 are not a bad thing

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner (works on Python2.7)

```
dict([(k, x.get(k,[])+y.get(k,[])) for k in set(x)|set(y)])
```

and a  not very pretty one that can digest non-lists

```
 dict([(k, [a for b in [x.get(k,[])]+[y.get(k,[])] for a in (b if isinstance(b, list) else [b])]) for k in set(x)|set(y)])
```

Comment: Nice! I knew there was a one-liner! It would take me a minute to figure out what it did if I saw it though.

Comment: Thanks Paul, nice one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution for you:

```
def append_dicts(x, y):
    z = dict(y)
    for k, v in x.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            z[k].extend(v)
        if isinstance(v, int):
            z[k].append(v)
    return z


x = {"a": [1] }
y = {"a": [2, 3], "b": [2] }
print(append_dicts(x, y))
# {'a': [2, 3, 1], 'b': [2]}

x = {"a": 1 }
y = {"a": [2, 3], "b": [2] }
print(append_dicts(x, y))
# {'a': [2, 3, 1], 'b': [2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accumulating functions: one which accepts duplicates and one which does not...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import defaultdict
from sets import Set

def combineUnique(input_dict_list):
    accumulating_dict = defaultdict(Set)
    for d in input_dict_list:
        for key,values in d.items():
            for value in values:
                accumulating_dict[key].add(value)
    return accumulating_dict

def combineWithDuplicates(input_dict_list):
    accumulating_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for d in input_dict_list:
        for key,value in d.items():
            accumulating_dict[key].extend(value)
    return accumulating_dict

if __name__=='__main__':

    x = {"a": [1, 2] }
    y = {"a": [2, 3], "b": [2] }


    print "With duplicates..."
    print combineWithDuplicates([x,y])

    print "Unique..."
    print combineUnique([x,y])
```

Returns...

```
With duplicates...
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 2, 3], 'b': [2]})
Unique...
defaultdict(<class 'sets.Set'>, {'a': Set([1, 2, 3]), 'b': Set([2])})
```